# Убрать редирект на собственную страницу ошибки

Tags: http-status-code-404, .htaccess, php

Как сделать так, чтобы редирект на собственную страницу ошибки не происходил. То есть если страница например не существует, то пользователь остается на этой странице, а не перенаправляется на 404.html, но при этом выводится содержимое 404.html

Answer (score 1):

зависит от конкретной реализации.